# iOS: Retaining connectivity with band

Tags: ios, microsoft-band

I have 2 apps on the app store with Tiles on the MS Band- (Band Time Tracker and Band List).  Both of these suffer from the same issue: over time the connection to the band is lost, events generated in the Band do not trigger code execution on the app.

What types of mitigating strategies can I use to ensure that events always trigger code execution on the phone?

Right now the only thing I have included is haptic feedback to notify the user that the event was accepted.